# Yii2: How to disabled or readonly a Select2 widget?

Tags: php, html, yii2, jquery-select2, disabled-input

I use a widget based on [select2.github.io](https://select2.github.io/options.html) and I need it to be readonly so the user can see a default select option but it can't be changed and I think this widget doesn't have this option.

Is there a general solution for any Select2 widget?

```
$form->field($model, 'id_color')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'items' => ['1' => 'blue', '2' => 'red', '3' => 'yellow']
])
```

Answer (score 9):

Well there is an option with the name `disabled` which can be passed as `true` or `false` which results in rendering a disabled select or enabled.

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'id_color')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'items' => ['1' => 'blue', '2' => 'red', '3' => 'yellow']
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'disabled' => true
        ]
    ]);
?>
```

**BUT, before you use it you should be aware that disabled inputs are not submitted along with the form as part of the post array**, and the `readonly` property `[was removed in 4.0 and higher versions](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3387#issuecomment-104961591). So you might have to do a workaround of adding a hidden input for the disabled select which holds the id for the current selected option for the disabled select2.

so add the following to your form and you are good to go

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'id_color')->hiddenInput() ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use pluginEvents to disable.

```
$form->field($model, 'id_color')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ['1' => 'blue', '2' => 'red', '3' => 'yellow'],
    'options' => ['class' =>'myclass'],
    'pluginEvents' => [
        "select2:opening" => "function() { $('.myclass').attr('disabled', true); }",
    ], 
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS method if you would like..

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'id_color')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ['1' => 'blue', '2' => 'red', '3' => 'yellow'],
    'readonly' => true,
]); ?>


<style type="text/css">
select[readonly].select2-hidden-accessible + .select2-container {
  pointer-events: none;
  touch-action: none;

  .select2-selection {
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  .select2-selection__arrow,
  .select2-selection__clear {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Select2 you can use attribute 'readonly' for 'options'

```
'options' => [
    'readonly' => true
],
```

For example

```
echo $form->field($model, 'sazba')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => $listData,
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => '--- Vyberte ---',
        'multiple' => false,
        'class' => 'hide',
        'id' => 'all_sazba',
        'value' => $model->sazba,
        'readonly' => true
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add

Answer (score 0):

Inside the options attribute add a new options with the list of ids to put in a disabled state

'options' => ArrayHelper::map(Recipiente::find()->where(['activo'=>0])->all(),'id',function ($data){ return ['disabled' => true];}),

```
echo $form->field($model, 'recipiente_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
  'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Recipiente::find()->all(), 'id', 'nombre'),                                                   
  'language' => \Yii::$app->language,
  'options' => [
      'placeholder' => '',
      // Desactivar Elementos
      'options' => ArrayHelper::map(Recipiente::find()->where(['activo'=>0])->all(),'id',function ($data){ return ['disabled' => true];}),
  ],
  'pluginOptions' => [
      'allowClear' => false
  ],
])->label('Recipiente');
```